# How to get average of first two numbers in array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, double, average

I cant figure out how to get just the average of the first 2 numbers in the array, and then the first 3 numbers.  I am getting error on these lines. `average(numbers[0],numbers[1]));` and `average(numbers[0],numbers[1],numbers[2]));`  here is my code.

```
public class NoVarargsTest{
    // calculate average
    public static double average(double[] numbers){
        double total = 0.0;
        // calculate total using the enhanced for statement
        for (double d : numbers){                
            total += d;
        }                          
        return (total / (double)numbers.length);
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        double d1 = 10.0;
        double d2 = 20.0;
        double d3 = 30.0;
        double d4 = 40.0;

        double[] numbers= new double[4];
        numbers[0] = 10.0;
        numbers[1] = 20.0;
        numbers[2] = 30.0;
        numbers[3] = 40.0;

        if (args.length == 0)
            System.out.println("No Command Line arguments");
        else {

            System.out.println("You provided " + args.length
                    + " arguments");

            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("args[" + i + "]: "
                        + args[i]);
            }
        }

        System.out.printf("d1 = %.1f%nd2 = %.1f%nd3 = %.1f%nd4 = %.1f%n%n",numbers[0],numbers[1], numbers[2], numbers[3]);
        System.out.printf("Average of d1 and d2 is %.1f%n",
        average(numbers[0],numbers[1]));
        System.out.printf("Average of d1, d2 and d3 is %.1f%n",
        average(numbers[0],numbers[1],numbers[2]));
        System.out.printf("Average of d1, d2, d3 and d4 is %.1f%n",
        average(numbers)); 
    }

} // end class NoVarargsTest
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use varargs, you must declare your method signature as:

```
public static double average(double... numbers){
```

`numbers` will then be a `double[]` within your method.

This is specified by [JLS §8.4.1: Formal Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4).

Comment: I never get a chance to use varargs. I like this solution.

Comment: I personally would rather use this way but I need to learn how to use both ways.

Answer (score 2):

Your `public static double average(double[] numbers)` method's parameter is a double[] array, but you just pass two double values here: `average(numbers[0],numbers[1]));`

To solve this either change your method to `public static double average(double... numbers)` or pass an array: `average(new double[] {numbers[0], numbers[1]})`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class NoVarargsTest
{
    // calculate average
    public static double average(double[] numbers)
    {

        double total = 0.0;
        // calculate total using the enhanced for statement
        for (double d : numbers)
        {
            total += d;
        }
        return total / (double)numbers.length;
    }

    // prints the wording around the array
    private static void driver(double[] numbers)
    {
        System.out.println("The average of " + Arrays.toString(numbers) + " is "+average(numbers));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        driver(new double[] {10});
        driver(new double[] {10, 20});
        driver(new double[] {10, 20, 30});
    }

} // end class VarargsTest
```

Comment: It was originally this public static double average(double... numbers) but my assignment asks to Write a program named NoVarargsTest that is identical to 7.20 in section 7.13 (page 282 of the print edition) but use an array of doubles in place of the varargs.  Make certain to understand how to do it both ways. Now alter it so that it reads the values as command-line arguments if they exist and if not, it uses the data provided in your original program.

Comment: Is this edited code still using the varargs @Alexandre Santos